# Pulling data from parse in swift as an array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a list of competitions in a class on parse named "Competitions", and I need to pull the list of competitions from said class to populate an array to populate a UI PickerView. What is the easiest way possible to complete this?

Thank you.

//edit with code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var compQuery = PFQuery(className:"Competitions")
    compQuery.whereKey("teamID", equalTo:"1")
    compQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (competitions: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Do something with the found objects
            for competition in competitions {
                NSLog("%@", competition["compName"] as String)
                self.competitionArray += [competition["compName"] as String]
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
}
```

// Edited with new errors
Since I am adding the objects to a UIPicker for the user to select a value, I used this to get the objects as an array of strings,

```
var competitionArrayString:Array = [competitionArray as AnyObject as [String]]
```

however I am receiving the error that my class does not have the member "competitionArray"

```
import UIKit
import Swift
import Parse

class CompetitionViewController: UIViewController  {
var competitionArrayString:Array = [""]
var competitionArray:NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var compQuery = PFQuery(className:"Competitions")
    compQuery.whereKey("teamID", equalTo:"1")

    self.competitionArray = NSMutableArray()

    compQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (competitions: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Do something with the found objects
            for competition in competitions {
                NSLog("%@", competition["compName"] as String)
                self.competitionArray.addObject([competition["compName"] as String])
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
}

var competitionArrayString:Array = [competitionArray as AnyObject as [String]]

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return competitionArrayString.count
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return competitionArrayString[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    var selectedData = competitionArrayString[row]
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setValue(selectedData, forKey: "competitionData");
    userDefaults.synchronize();

    println("You Selected: \(selectedData)")


}

}
```

Comment: This should be a fairly straight-forward task... What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I understand how to reference the objectID in the table by using the code as supplied in the documentation, however I am trying to reference a column and put the data in to an array

Comment: You can query an entire class using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` with a PFQuery of your class name

Comment: I've got that. How do I get the queried data into the array

Comment: It's already returned in array form... You really have to post your code if you want any help beyond that.

Comment: In that case, how do I output something other than the objectID. Will edit the original post with the code when I get home.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Posed the code. I got it to pull the data, but putting it in  an array is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) To add an element to an array in Swift you have to use `addObject`, not `+=` and (2) you make sure you're initializing your array, ex:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var compQuery = PFQuery(className:"Competitions")
    compQuery.whereKey("teamID", equalTo:"1")

    self.competitionArray = NSMutableArray()

    compQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (competitions: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Do something with the found objects
            for competition in competitions {
                NSLog("%@", competition["compName"] as String)
                self.competitionArray.addObject(competition["compName"] as String)
            }
            self.pickerControl.reloadAllComponents()  // <- reload your picker's data
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did help, however check the original post for an update with new errors and see if you have any idea to why I am getting these.

Thank you.

Comment: @TylerPatrick Where/what are the errors? I don't see anything about them in your post...

Comment: Just added them sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TylerPatrick This line `var competitionArrayString:Array = [competitionArray as AnyObject as [String]]` can't be used outside of a method or outside of the class... That line doesn't belong there.

Comment: @TylerPatrick Actually it's the same issue. You can't have this line `var competitionArrayString:Array = [competitionArray as AnyObject as [String]]` outside of a function. Also it's a duplicate declaration of competitionArrayString and that's not OK...

Comment: I am trying to fill a UIPicker with an array and I can't use an array of objects, they need to be converted to strings correct?

Comment: @TylerPatrick You've already converted them to strings within `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` with this line: `self.competitionArray.addObject([competition["compName"] as String])`.  This line outside of your functions is completely unnecessary `var competitionArrayString:Array = [competitionArray as AnyObject as [String]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69575/discussion-between-tyler-patrick-and-lyndsey-scott).

and 

In that case, why am I receiving an error that 'return competitionArray[row]' is AnyObject and therefore convertible to string?